# ASP.NET GridView BackColor update on column sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, conditional-formatting, backcolor

I have a `GridView` tied to a table in a SQL Database so that it loads onto a page after login to my website.

When the page with the `GridView` is first loaded. I step through the rows on the table and change the `BackColor` for each row depending on it's "Status" column (i.e. if it's "Incomplete" make it red or green if it's "Complete"). When you sort the table by another column then the `BackColor` goes away.

I attempt to run the same function to step through the rows and change all the `BackColors` on the `GridView1_Sorted` event but the table remains without any color changes. Same goes for using the `GridView1_Load` event. However adding a button in and tieing that button's click to the same formatting code lets me apply the `BackColors` after sorting.

This tells me I'm probably misunderstanding something in how the `Sorted` event works. Can anyone tell me how to get the `GridView` set up properly so that I can sort by some column and still re-apply my `BackColor` formatting?

Comment: You might want to hook into the RowDataBound event. It's been a while since I've done WebForms but if the datasource is rebound to the grid upon sort then try calling the function each time a row is bound.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for the tip. I thought that Sorted was the right event to go with for this but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim stStatus As String = e.Row.Cells(1).Text ' INDEX OF YOUR STATUS COLUMN
    For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
        If stStatus = "Incomplete" Then
            cell.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else If stStatus = "Complete" Then
            cell.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Put this code in the `RowDataBound` event of your `GridView`

Comment: Worked like a charm. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.